# Azure AD authentication and authorization with asp.net core 2.2 in .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 api hosted within .Net Framework 4.8. The reason for such an architecture was to allow some direct referencing of libs built in legacy dot net framework. Currently the API is using ADFS and now there is a need to move to Azure AD. I have configured Swagger and can authenticate against the Azure AD by selecting a scope. However, authorization does not work for a number of reasons. Cannot use  app.UseAuthorization(); in Configure() because Microsoft.Asp.Net.Core package (any version) does not install on .net framework 4.8.
Microsoft.Identity.Web package also requires .net Core 3 or higher
Any help to implement Authorization with Azure AD will be highly appreciated.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            AspNetCore.Serilog.DependencyInjection.UseIdentityLogging(app);
            app.UseLogging();
            app.UseExceptionHandling();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseAzureSwaggerUi(_azureAdConfig);
            app.UseCors(policy =>
                policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:60216", "https://localhost:60216")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType)
            );
        app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();//not available
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       //Azure ad
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("AzureAD", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RequiredRoleAuthorisationHandler>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddSwaggerOAuth2Authorization(_azureAdConfig);
            services.RegisterAuthorisationPolicies();
        ConfigureSwagger(services);
            ConfigureApplicationServices(services);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: If HttpContext is null, I get an error when doing AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf, like UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accesstoken, 
 "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
            var result = app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync().Result;